# angular.js trigger ng-show within callback

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, callback, settimeout, ng-show

i tried to trigger an ng-show by editing the scope within a setTimeout function. setTimeout is a placeholder here for a database query callback.

index.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
<div ng-controller="c1">

    <div ng-show="{{show}}"  >

        test it

    </div>

</div>
```

script.js:

```
var amTestNgShow = angular.module('amTestNgShow',[]);

amTestNgShow.controller('c1', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    // this works: $scope.show = true;

    setTimeout(function(){

        $scope.show = true; // works not

        // does not help: $scope.$apply();

    }, 1000)

}]);
```

how is this doable within setTimeout? thx!

http://plnkr.co/edit/RPS2vZAlVfhliQKteSSK

Update: As explained above, setTimeout is not the problem, it's only used to generate a reproducable stackoverflow question. In my project I builded a service:

```
amProject1.service('asBasic', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    var asBasic = {};

    asBasic.docName = '';

    var doc = {};

    asBasic.get = function(id){

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({method:'GET', url: '/' + this.docName + '/' + id})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){

                if(data === undefined){

                    deferred.reject("The requested " + asBasic.docName + " was not found.")

                }

                doc = data;
                deferred.resolve(doc);

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){

                deferred.reject(status);

            })

       return deferred.promise;

    }


    return asBasic;

}]);
```

to use it like

```
amProject1.controller('acDoc1', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'asBasic', function($scope, $routeParams, asBasic){

    asBasic.docName = 'doc1';

    // this works: $scope.show = true;

    asBasic.get($routeParams._id)
        .then(function(data){

            $scope.doc1 = data;

            $scope.show = true; // works not

            // does not help: $scope.$apply();

            // ...

        }
        // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because setTimeout is outside of the `$scope` processes. Inject and use `$timeout` instead.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout)

Eg:

```
amTestNgShow.controller('c1', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.show = true;
    }, 1000);
}]);
```

If you did want to instead use `$scope.apply`, I think you simply had the usage wrong. You don't call `$scope.apply()` after your scope edits, you instead put them inside the apply function:

```
$scope.apply(function(){
    $scope.show = true;
});
```

Comment: Thx, your $timeout solution works, but this was not exactly the problem. Please see my update above. Wrapping the scope edits with $scope.apply does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you are binding to {{show}} in your template. The curly brackets should be removed since they are inside an AngularJS attribute.

Answer (score 1):

A late review of my post: mrida was right (thx), the curly brackets must be removed ...

```
<div ng-controller="c1">

    <div ng-show="show">

        test it

    </div>

</div>
```

It is also possible to solve it with ng-style.

html:

```
...

<div ng-controller="c1">

    <div ng-style="{'visibility': show}">

        test it

    </div>

</div>

...
```

controller:

```
...

setTimeout(function(){

    $scope.show = "visible"; // or $scope.show = "hidden"

    $scope.$apply();

}, 1000)

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` and `'show'` instead of `'{{show}}'`

```
<div ng-show="show">
    test it
</div>
```